# WPF Binding Alternatives / Enhancements

Tags: python, wpf, binding, pybinding

I love WPF bindings, but I often find myself wish I could do a **little** more.  PyBindings seem like a good start, but the Python syntax seems very clunky and out of place in a XAML file.  Are there any alternatives out there?  Something with a simpler syntax, that allows for quick comparisons & conversions so that I don't have to write (and maintain) silly 1-liner IValueConverters?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.thinkbottomup.com.au/site/blog/Embedding_DLR_Scripts_in_XAML_Part_1

This is page discusses various ways of bolting the DLR onto bindings and using them in interesting ways to do get all sorts of languages into your XAML.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.fikrimvar.net/lestirelim/?p=15

In this blog post, the author describes how he used a LINQ expression parser provided by Microsoft to generate Binding Converters on the fly that actually run a bit of code to transform their input values.  Unlike PyBindings, you need to explicitly bind in the values you are going to use as variables in your expression, but the LINQ syntax seems far better suited for coexisting with the XAML's XML syntax.